# How to implement theme to html?

Tags: html, css, colors, themes, background-color

Okay so I'm 100% new to programming. The question format may also be wrong.
The Question: theme on html?
Still beginner on html. wanted it to look aesthetically pleasing to my eyes at least with what I've learnt. No CSS knowledge yet. I've been little bit searching whatever i feel like putting on my page(emojis).
I've searched Google and did what was written but it still doesn't display the theme.
Okay so here's the code so you can see, will add more things later as i learn(I know it's nothing for you all):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#f7cac9">
       <title>Galaxia
       </title>
  </head>
    <body>

  <h3 style = "position:absolute; right:150px; top:-10px; background-color:pink;">
    Welcome to my weird abode &#x1F98B;
  </h3>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- added two br tags because otherwise heading and paragraph overlap -->
  
  <div class="coder">
    <p>This is a html example from me for now,
        <br>
        have fun.:) </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is what CSS is, HTML by itself is pretty much just text and images.  CSS is used for styling and coloring.   When you wrote ```"position:absolute; right:150px; top:-10px; background-color:pink;"``` that is css

Comment: I see. I just thought It was possible through HTML that's all. But if it's only through CSS, then that's just something else I'll study later on the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to add styles to your HTML page, you use css (with the file extension .css -- for example `styles.css`). To make the styles visible on your html page, in the head section you would include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>`. For instance, in the css file, you could include:

```
h3 {
    color: #f7cac9;
}
```

Then, after adding the link rel, the h3 elements in your html page would be pink. Hope this helps! Alternatively, you could add  tags in your html page.

Here's an example of adding css to an html page. By adding .coder {background: green}, the background-color turns green:

```css
.coder {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#f7cac9">
       <title>Galaxia
       </title>
  </head>
    <body>

  <h3 style = "position:absolute; right:150px; top:-10px; background-color:pink;">
    Welcome to my weird abode &#x1F98B;
  </h3>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- added two br tags because otherwise heading and paragraph overlap -->
  
  <div class="coder">
    <p>This is a html example from me for now,
        <br>
        have fun.:) </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guys posts.

- **HTML** - is a markup language.  You will say for the browser:  Hey this is a paragraph ... `<p>This is a paragraph</p>`
- **CSS** - You will make things looks nicer.  You can change all the colors, backgrounds, fonts, sizes, margins...

One place to find a quick tutorial and it is also a good place to know is [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

It is famous and a lot of people use it.

I hope that you keep pushing.

The first step is the hardest one!